# Restarting a fragment activity onreceive in broadcast receiver

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I have an ongoing activity but once I receive a broadcast from the `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE`  I wish to display to the users that there is no internet connection from an already active fragment activity

```
Container app = (Container) context.getApplicationContext();
app.recreate();
```

But the above code does not work in the `onreceive` method in my broadcast intent reciever and cause a can not cast android app to fragment activity Container.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Don't you want to use a Toast????

Comment: @Sheychan no I don't, I want to be able to control the activity from the broadcast receiver, is it possible?

Comment: no experience but I have something in mind.. Would you like a Shared preferences approach?

Comment: @Sheychan sounds cool but where do I do the check, in the onresume method of the fragment activity?

Comment: On each time you want to show the no internet alert or view

Comment: I am thinking of saving the state on a preference then on activity a function monitors the change then if it is not connected we will do the addition of view with the alert of No Internet Connection.. This is the approach Im seeing

Answer (score 0):

> I wish to display to the users that there is no internet connection
>   from an **already active fragment activity**

Try having a *"BaseFragmentActivity"* that has a broadcast receiver member that does this. And each `FragmentActivity` in your app should `extend` it.